# centering text in navigation bar CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the navigation bar a new version of my startup's website.  The new version is hidden at http://www.pintsteinpro.com/alternateMain.html. If you click on any links, you will be taken to my main website and there are no links redirecting you to the hidden website.

I'm working with a web design from binarytheme.com that can be found here:  http://binarytheme.com/bootstrap-background-slideshow-template-vega/

I found the part to the code that controls the text:

```
.nav a {
    color:#ffffff !important;
```

but no amount of inserting CSS to center the text seems to work. I have tried:

```
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
left:50%;top:0;
```

I also tried to modify `.navbar-header a` to center the text with no luck.

This section controls the background color and inserting various centering code inside `nav` has also not worked.

```
nav {
    background: #fff;
    z-index:99;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    min-height: 50px; 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Any ideas about what I should try next?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `margin: 0 auto` alongside with specified `width` property to center your div, e.g.

```
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
}
```

Note that I've removed `float: left`

Comment: .navbar-header a {
    color:#ffffff !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 700px;
didn't change anything.

.nav a {
    color:#ffffff !important;
    text-align:center;
    position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
   width: 700px;
made it so that the text is stacked on top of each other but still off center.

I couldn't find .nav a {
    color:#ffffff !important;
    text-align:center;
    position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
   width: 700px;

.navbar-nav {

Comment: You need to set those styles to `.navbar-nav`, not to `.navbar-header a`

Answer (score 1):

Set `text-align: center` to :

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form{
   border-color: #101010;
   text-align: center;
}
```

And `display: inline-block` to :

```
.navbar-nav{
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I have removed the `float: left`

Comment: Still no luck! Is there a way to attach css files to posts on here? I found

}
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
}

and changed it to: }
.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

I also found
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form{
   border-color: #101010;
}
and changed it to
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form{
   border-color: #101010;
   text-align: center;
}
Thanks for the attempts but when I try this new code it still has not centered the navigation bar

Comment: I'm on your website and the menu is centered, so it's ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Do easy steps.

1. Add `.navbar-nav{width: 100%; text-align: center;}`
2. Remove `.navbar-nav > li {float: left;}`
3. Add `.navbar-nav > li {display: inline-block;}`

Comment: thanks,  I had a hard time figuring out where exactly I should do step 1 since there are multiple .navbar-nav{s in the file but the last two steps gave me how to finally get the navbar centered!